# SSRS error reporting and monitoring

Tags: monitoring, ssrs-2008

We have a SSRS 2008 server running and doing daily reports for us. Sometimes these reports will fail. The reasons for this kind of failure isn't so much of importance, as the fact that I haven't been able to find any way to get informed if there are any failed subscriptions.

So my question in a nutshell is:
What do you use to keep track of your SSRS installation? and is there some obvious "send an email to this address if stuff breaks" field i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the answer in this link:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/EEB7CC21-5A8D-4E35-BE42-585E5CF0F6DA

Comment: P.s. I'll give you a vote up, once i get to the magic 15 rep required to do so.